# R: color coding model diagnostic plots

Tags: r, plot

```
library(nlme)
SeedID <- unique(Loblolly$Seed)
set.seed(3)
group1 = sample(SeedID, 7)
group1_ind = which(Loblolly$group == 1)
Loblolly$group = ifelse(Loblolly$Seed %in% group1, 1, 0)

fm1 <- nlme(height ~ SSasymp(age, Asym, R0, lrc),
            data = Loblolly,
            fixed = Asym + R0 + lrc ~ 1,
            random = Asym ~ 1,
            start = c(Asym = 103, R0 = -8.5, lrc = -3.3))

stdRes = resid(fm1, type = "p")
fitted = fitted(fm1)
plot(stdRes ~ fitted)
points(stdRes[group1_ind] ~ fitted[group1_ind], col = "blue")
```

I have a data set with 14 distinct `Seed`. I randomly split them up into 2 groups (0 or 1, 7 Seeds per group) and fit a model. I graphed the residuals by group (black for group 0, blue for group 1) and it looks just fine.
[image]

But I can't figure out how to color-code the QQ plot by group on the same plot.

```
qqnorm(stdRes)
points(qqnorm(stdRes[group1_ind]), col = "blue")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the values returned (invisibly) from `qqnorm` and then use those to draw your points

```
dd <- as.data.frame(qqnorm(stdRes))
points(y~x, dd[group1_ind,], col = "blue")
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify - what are the `y` and `x` here?

Comment: Those are from the values returned from `qqnorm`. See the description in the "Value" section of the `?qqnorm` help page.